# how to sign an apk file with keystore(eg. platform.keystore)?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, keystore, sign

i want to sign an apk with platform.keystore,

i know i can build a apk with source code using keystore in eclipse.

but how sign an apk file with platform.keystore without knowing the passwd and alias of the keystore? 
Is that possible? 
how does eclipse do this job sign from source code?

any help will be appreciate, thanks in advance!

Comment: Eclipse asks you the store and alias passwords when you build with a real (non-debug) key.  Signing with the platform key would require require that you know it - is it your android build or one from someone wiling to share the key with you?  Or sign your apk for you?  If this is a commercial android release, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: the platform.keystore is from the cooperator company, but they didn't provide the platform.x509.pem platform.pk8, so i come to this question

Comment: They either need to provide those to you, or if they don't want to then you send them the apk and they sign it and send it back to you (and maybe you use a build signed with test keys for your in progress work)

Answer (score 0):

> but how sign an apk file with
>   platform.keystore without knowing the
>   passwd and alias of the keystore? Is
>   that possible?

You can't use a passworded key without knowing the password.

Comment: eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android->Build->Custom debug keystore>Browse(platform.keystore)   then eclipse could build the apk file with platform.keystore, eclipse doesn't know the passwd either. how eclipse do so?